# SBT - cannot run program tar in directory

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to publish an SBT plugin (version 2.10) with the `universal:publish` command

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Running with tar -pcvf /tmp/sbt_4d2c5ced/my-plugin-0.1.0.tar my-plugin-0.1.0
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "tar" (in directory "/tmp/sbt_4d2c5ced/my-plugin-0.1.0"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I have other SBT projects this work for, however they aren't SBT plugins so not sure if this is making the difference.

Below is the `Build.scala` from my SBT plugin:

```
val pluginName = "my-plugin"
val organisationId = "org.me"
val pluginVersion = envOrElse(s"""${pluginName.toUpperCase.replace("-", "_")}_VERSION""", "999-SNAPSHOT")

lazy val plugin = Project(pluginName, file("."))
  .enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin, UniversalDeployPlugin)
  .settings(sbtPlugin := true)
  .settings(version := pluginVersion)
  .settings(organization := organisationId)
  .settings(scalacOptions := Seq("-deprecation"))
  .settings(crossVersion := CrossVersion.binary)
  .settings(crossPaths := false)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq())
  .settings(UniversalPlugin.projectSettings)
  .settings(UniversalDeployPlugin.projectSettings)
  .settings(PublishingSettings.publishingSettings)
```

Any advice as to how I can get this working would be great, this is stopping me publish artifacts. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add which version of the sbt plugins you are using in that plugin project?

Comment: sbt-native-packager isn't the right tool to publish sbt plugins. You publish an sbt-plugin like any other jar artifact. Native-packager is for building application packages, not jar artifacts.